# Functions in python task

Tags: python

My task has these instructions:

You are prohibited from using arithmetic in this question. Rather, to earn credit, you must use     double and increment somehow.

- Prompt the user to input a number.
- Convert the input to an integer and store it in the variable n.
- Print the value 2*(n+1)

I am just receiving an error message saying: ' you need to call double'.

This is my code

```
x = input('2')
x = int(x)

def increment(xs: int):
   result = []
    x += 1
   return x + 1


def double(x: int):
    result = []
    for x in xs:
        result.append(x*2)
    return 2*x

print(2*(x + 1))
```

I've searched and watched multiple videos on calling double but do not understand where the mistake is. If i could have assistance on what to change in my code, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use the `increment` and `double` functions instead of directly printing `2*(x + 1)`. You have errors in your function implementations, though.

Comment: why you are initialising result as a `list`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're required to return `2 * (x + 1)` without using any arithmetic operators? That's an insanely tricky task.

Comment: Well, maybe not. There are actually tons of valid answers...

Comment: How you do this will, to a certain extent, depend on your definition of "arithmetic". You probably mean that you're not allowed to use operators such as +-/\* But can you, for example, use the built-in *sum()* function?

Answer (score 0):

First, prompt the user to enter a number and store it in the variable `x`. Then convert `x` to an integer and store in `n`.

```
x = input('Enter a number: ')
n = int(x)
```

Define `increment()` and `double()` functions:

```
def increment(x: int) -> int:
    return x + 1

def double(x: int) -> int:
    return x * 2
```

Print result:

```
result = double(increment(n))
print(result)
```

Comment: I suspect that *x + 1* is considered to be "arithmetic" in this context

Answer (score 0):

Short and concise:

```py
print(sum((sum((x, x)), 2)))
```

Explanation:

```py
print(                # Print out
  sum((               # the sum of a tuple
    sum((x, x)), 2    # which contains the sum of x and x (2 * x) and 2
  ))                  # (2 * x) + 2 == 2 * (x + 1)
)                     # Simple as that!
```

***Edit:*** I found out a few other solutions; thanks @MichaelButscher for making me do so.

```py
s = ''.join(' ' for i in range(x))
print(len(f' {s}{s} '))

# Or

s = (' ' for i in range(x))
print(len([*s, *s, ' ', ' ']))
```

### Original answer

First, get user's input, then convert it to an integer using `int()`:

```py
x = input('Input: ') # Input is just the prompt text
x = int(x)
```

Second, define `increment()`, which adds 1 to its argument, and `double()`, which doubles its argument.

```py
def increment(x):
    return x + 1

def double(x):
    return 2 * x
```

Call them with `x` passed as argument, then print `x` out:

```py
x = increment(x)
x = double(x)
print(x)
```

A terse version of everything explained above:

```py
x = int(input('Input: '))

def increment(x):
    return x + 1

def double(x):
    return 2 * x

print(double(increment(x)))
```

If you're actually required to return `2 * (x + 1)` without using any arithmetic operators, whoever gave you that task needs to rethink about their decision, as this is a very tricky task which makes even experienced programmers struggle. If you don't understand this, just ignore.

```py
# https://iq.opengenus.org/addition-using-bitwise-operations/
def bitwise_add(a, b):
    return bitwise_add((a & b) << 1, a ^ b) if a else b

print(bitwise_add(1, x) << 1)
```

Comment: Aren't bit operators arithmetic, too?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Maybe, but in that case I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

A completely arithmetic-free solution but it only works for non-negative ints up to 1 billion:

```
def increment(x):
    found = False
    for i in range(1000000002):
        if found:
            return i
        if x == i:
            found = True

def double(x):
    for i in range(x):
        x = increment(x)
    return x


n = input('2')
n = int(n)

print(double(increment(n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the prohibition actually means that operators such as +, -, *, /, can not be used.

This can conveniently be achieved with the built-in *sum()* function (unless that's considered to be "arithmetic").

```
def double(n):
    return sum((n, n))

x = int(input('Input your value: '))

print(double(sum((x, 1))))
```

Comment: I think under the hood of `sum()` there should be `+` operator.

Comment: @tmc Of course you're right but that wouldn't be a Python + operator. It will be in C and my interpretation of the question (which may be wrong) is that traditional Python arithmetic operators are barred from the solution

Answer (score -1):

Your increment function had indentation issues. I rewrote the code this should work.

```
n = input('2')
n = int(n)


def increment(x: int):
    return x + 1


def double(x: int):
    return 2 * x


print(double(increment(n)))
```

Comment: one condition you not satisfy..! `prohibited from using arithmetic`